# Repairing the HeapSort - strange time

Tags: c++, arrays, heapsort

Does this program measure time well? Because I have very strange results, when the "n" has 1 000 000 elements the time is 0.06 but I'm sure it's too fast. Where is the problem? In QSort (pivot - median of 3 and elements = rand()%100) I have 97810 miliseconds... What is the reason for this? Is something missing or wrong in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
const int n = 100000;

void heapify(int arr[], int n, int root)
{
    int largest = root; 
    const int left = 2 * root + 1;
    const int right = left + 1; 

    if (left < n && arr[left] > arr[largest])
        largest = left;

    if (right < n && arr[right] > arr[largest])
        largest = right;

    if (largest != root) {
        swap(arr[root], arr[largest]);

        heapify(arr, n, largest);
    }
}

void heapSort(int arr[], int n)
{

    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(arr, n, i);

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);

        heapify(arr, i, 0);
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int *arr = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++)
        arr[i] = rand()%100;
 //   cout << "Not-Sorted array is "<<endl<<endl;
 //   printArray(arr, n);
    cout<<endl;

    const auto start = clock();
    heapSort(arr, n);
    const auto stop = clock();
    const auto time = static_cast<double>(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

//    cout << "Sorted array is "<<endl<<endl;
 //   printArray(arr, n);

    cout<<endl<< "Time is : "<<time<<endl<<endl;
}
```

Comment: are you saying 0.06 is too fast ? and asking why ?

Comment: Compared to QSort it's a big difference, so I think it is too fast and I don't know why, maybe I have error in code... I don't know, so I ask

Comment: I would put it the other way: 97 seconds to sort 1,000,000 elements is a lot, you might have a problem there. 0.06 seconds sounds reasonable to me. You can expect ~10^8 operations to fit in one second (just an approximation used in competitive programming, there are a lot of factors involved).

Comment: Something different: Try to avoid comments that repeat the code. State only what is important and special.

Comment: Ok. So problem is in QSort. Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried to compare against a ```std::vector``` and ```std::sort```?